# How to make R executable file

Tags: r, executable-format

Is it possible to create an executable file where I can just upload the excels and an output is generated based on the coding and without sharing it as well.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux or OSX you can make an R script double clickable with the shebang trick:

1. Add `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` as the first line
2. Make the script executable with `chmod +x`

On OSX, there is also the option to convert an R script into an application bundle with [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus). On Windows, I do not know whether this is easily achievable at all, especially as executables usually are not placed in the search path on Windows.